# Need to filter only extended ASCII characters such as Ä, å, à, etc

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to read a set of text files and get the content and this part is successful. The issue is content consists of some extended ACII characters and I used the following to filter those characters:

```
$contents = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $contents);
```

This erases all extended ASCII characters plus the needed characters such as apostrophes, quotes, etc.

How should I change the preg_replace to do this?

Comment: What you have posted will not remove quotes and apostrophes. Can you include some of the text that's getting edited?

Comment: For example: You d go to school. Should be "You'd go to school"

Comment: Don't you mean: "Youd go to school"?  And it's working for me.  Are you sure that "apostrophe" is not some other character that looks like   an apostrophe?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the ascii `'` or `"`, which are not in the range you are filtering. The problem is most likely windows smart quotes. Filter those before you run your replace and you'll have more joy ;)

For instance, [taken from this link](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php):

```
<?php 

function convert_smart_quotes($string) 
{ 
    $search = array(chr(145), 
                    chr(146), 
                    chr(147), 
                    chr(148), 
                    chr(151)); 

    $replace = array("'", 
                     "'", 
                     '"', 
                     '"', 
                     '-'); 

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}

$contents = convert_smart_quotes($contents);
$contents = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $contents);
var_dump($contents);

?>
```

Comment: I just noticed, when I first give the following two line and then I give the preg_replace for ASCII, the content comes perfectly alright but there are 1000s of text files and I can't make sure that other text files have the same.

Comment: $contents = str_replace('',"&rsquo;",$contents);
                $contents = str_replace('',"&ndash;",$contents);
                
                
                $contents = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $contents);

Comment: Thanks to all of you and really appreciate it! The issue was all my text files were unicode and once I convert them to utf-8, never got any extended ASCII characters.